# 2 random Letters followed by 4 digits

Tags: python-3.x

```
def tradeid_generator():
    tradeid = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for x in range(2))
    return ''.join(tradeid,random.choice(string.digits) for x in range(4))
```

I need to get something like 2 random letters followed by 4 digits.

But I getting the following error:

> SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole
>   argument

Comment: How about `'{}{:04}'.format(tradeid, random.randrange(10000))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply join your strings:

```
tradedid + ''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for x in range(4))
```

Otherwise, your return statement has error in `join`. You have two parameters there, while it takes one argument only, also `random.choice(string.digits) for x in range(4)` is a generator expression with no parentheses.

Comment: Simple and Brilliant :)